# Button has to be clicked twice to activate?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using vb.net VS 2015.

I have a button. The only changes I have made to the button are I added an image, set tabStop=false and removed the button text to use the image only.

When my code makes the button visible and go to click the button I have to click it twice before it runs the Yes_BTN_Click code. Anyone know why this is happening? It's like the 1st click selects the button then the 2nd click executes the button code.

I have two buttons" a Yes and a No button and they both act the same way.

I thought of a solution that may work but don't know how to code it as I'm just learning.

I was thinking I could add a MouseHoverOver code to select the button when hovering over it so it selects then requires only 1 click.

Comment: Check that form is not losing focus before clicking. What are the properties and events handling you have changed in the form and button

Comment: Thank you you hit it on the money it was a loop with application.doevents() causing the issue. Thank you